# How to solve the more than 1 argument error for json?

Tags: python, json

I am new to python. I am currently trying to extract only certain labels of a json file and create a new json file with the new labels. However when I try this code I get the following error.

```
 import json`enter code here`
 input_file=open('UK2.json', 'r')
 output_file=open('test.json', 'w')
 json_decode=json.load(input_file)
 result[]
 for item in json_decode:
     my_dict={}
     my_dict['fullname']=item.get('fullname')
     my_dict['id']=item.get('id')
     my_dict['likes']=item.get('likes')
     my_dict['replies']=item.get('replies')
     my_dict['retweets']=item.get('retweets')
     my_dict['text']=item.get('text')
     my_dict['timestamp']=item.get('timestamp')
     my_dict['user']=item.get('user')
     print(my_dict)
     result.append(my_dict)
back_json=json.dumps(result, output_file)
```

dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `json.dump()` instead of `json.dumps()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function you want is `json.dump`, which outputs to a file, and not `json.dumps`, which just returns the object in its string form.